# jQM autocomplete how to get the values for use on callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I am currently using JQM autocomplete, I can access the label $a.text() in the callback function but not the value... how do i access the value fields?

my JSON structure is

```
{
    "label": "TEST CLIENT ONE",
    "value": {
        "internalCustomerID": 1,
        "contactName": "DASDASDASD",
        "name": "TEST CLIENT ONE",
        "address": "SESAME STREET",
    }
}
$("#textinput2").autocomplete({
                target: $('#suggestions'),
                source: jsData,
                callback: function(e) {
                    var $a = $(e.currentTarget);
                    console.log("Selected a: " +$a);
                    $('#textinput2').val($a.text());
                    $('#textarea2').val(jsData[id].value.internalCustomerID+' '+jsData[id].value.address);
                    $("#textinput2").autocomplete('clear');
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
```

I would like to do this without having to search for the label again in the array... I am using http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/27/jQuery-Mobile-Autocomplete-now-available as my autocomplete.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

By default jqm autocomplete put's the "value" you populate, in the end of the "link" you give him (in the autocomplete function).

To overcome this I add to the `"jqm.autoComplete-1.3.js"` file in `line 27: (in the a tag)`

```
data-id="'+ value.value +
```

and then in your callback function you can do: `$a.attr("data-id")` to get your value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey guys...andy matthews here. I'm constantly looking to improve the jQM Autocomplete plugin. If you find something that's not working properly, or that you think could be improved I'd love for you to post an issue on Github. Even better would be to submit your additions in a pull request so that everyone can benefit.

Comment: @commadelimited I do not see this suggestion in 1.5 - perhaps I missed something...

Comment: I know that the version of autoComplete says 1.5.2, but the last version of jQueryMobile explicitly tested with autoComplete was 1.2. Other than minor fixes, I haven't updated autoComplete in almost 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Escape your JSON and put it into the href part (so it looks like #{x:1,y:2}, than unescape it back, like this:

```
    callback: function(e) {//on each suggested item after it's clicked
            var a = $(e.currentTarget);
           var hDec = str2array(a.attr('href').substr(1));
        now.we.have.an.array(hDec[0],  hDec[1]);
            $('#sym_suggest').val(a.text());
            $("#sym_suggest").autocomplete('clear').val(""); 
        },
```